# Sure I'm doing something very wrong with boost:replace_all. Sanity check please?

Tags: c++, string, replace

I wanted an efficient way to perform a search and replace on a string (actually it's a shader string), so I did a little research and came up with boost::replace_all.  My function is passed a string and a vector or pairs.  Each pair is a pair of strings; the search and replace with string.  I want to iterate this set of replacements, modifying the string in the process.  Here's what I came up with:

```
void 
Shader::Read(ShaderTypes type, std::string const & shader, std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> const & replace)
{
    // Perform search and replace on input string.

    std::string newShader = shader;

    std::for_each(replace.begin(), replace.end(), [newShader](std::pair<std::string, std::string> const & pair) {
        boost::replace_all(newShader, pair.first, pair.second);
    });




    // Create and compile shader.

    Read(type, newShader);
}
```

Now this won't compile.  I get a slew of errors from boost.  I think it's something to do with pair being const, but I'm not 100% certain.  When I tried manually creating a std::pair and calling replace_all with it, it worked.  Doesn't like the form it arrives from the lambda though.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should capture `newShader` by reference:

```
std::for_each(replace.begin(), replace.end(), [&newShader](...
```

Comment: Ah.  You genius.  I knew it was something daft like that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure newShader should be passed by reference to the lambda. And you don't have to give its name, you could automatically capture with [&].